# Saving payment info from controller

Tags: magento, model, controller, payment

I'm trying to save payment info from the controller, usually I do this in the model:

```
$payment->setTransactionAdditionalInfo(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment_Transaction::RAW_DETAILS,$raw);
```

But in the model I receive $payment as a pararmeter, now I'm trying this

```
$order = $this->getOrder();
$payment = $order->getPayment();
$payment->setTransactionAdditionalInfo(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment_Transaction::RAW_DETAILS,$raw);
```

But is not working, any idea how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, have to run addTransaction() first

```
$payment->addTransaction ( Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment_Transaction::TYPE_AUTH, null, false, null );
```